# How to migrate toasts from bootstrap 4 to 5?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Initializing toasts in `bootstrap-4` was as easy as: `$('.toast').toast(option);`

Now as `bootstrap-5` dropped `jquery` support, the require a different initialization approach:

```
var toastElList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.toast'));
var toastList = toastElList.map(function (toastEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Toast(toastEl, option)
});
```

But there is hardly any documentation about it.
Means: what is `option` here? And what should we do with the resulting `toastList`?

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/toasts/#usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `toastlist` will just hold the elements which are now initialized as Toasts (which you probably already know), I don't know if there's any use of it.
   In the SASS version, just doing a `new Toast(el)` initializes all the toasts, however the way you mention is how it is done in the CDN version.
2. `option` should be the options array you can pass onto the constructor, though I was not able to do it that way. However passing in data-bs-* attributes in the trigger element itself worked.
3. You can still just call the `toastEl.show()` where toastEl is the toast element itself. All the other methods and events work as well.

Given the new-ness of B5, hopefully the documentation will improve overtime.

Comment: Indeed calling `.show()` simply on all found elements of `toastList` shows the toast as expected. That was the missing peace.