# Bootstrap 5 : toast without jquery

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, toast

I am using Laravel 8 and want to show a sucess information (after a post for example). For the moment I did a simple alert using the session,like that :

```
    @if(Session::has('success'))
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
    {{ Session::get('success') }}
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">&nbsp;</button>
    @php
    Session::forget('success');
    @endphp
</div>
```

The result is fine :

[image]

I want now to display a toast instead of this alert. And if I have understood, BS5 allows now to use "toasts" without jquery. I tried to add this script in the @if section , but without success :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   
        var myAlert =document.getElementById('essai');//select id of toast
          var bsAlert = new bootstrap.Toast(myAlert);//inizialize it
          bsAlert.show();//show it
    
  </script>
```

my toast is :

```
<div class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" id="essai">
    <div class="toast-header">
      
      <strong class="me-auto">Bootstrap</strong>
      <small>11 mins ago</small>
      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="toast-body">
      Hello, world! This is a toast message.
    </div>
  </div>
```

Of course I have this error :

**Uncaught ReferenceError: bootstrap is not defined**

As I am not expert of JS into HTML page, any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this help you? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68437290/how-to-migrate-toasts-from-bootstrap-4-to-5/68441664#68441664

Comment: Yes It is the same problem, but does not help anymore. I tried a lot of things this afternoon without success. A sample is missing somewhere in the doc for those (like me) who are not js experts. I think I will keep my traditionnal alert class ;-)

Comment: Well here's how to do it in case you want: https://jsfiddle.net/deathstalkersid/e86a5Lvq/